# Why does the URI constructor remove part of path from the baseUri argument?

Tags: c#, uri

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:7777/BasePath/");
        Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, "/controller");
        Console.WriteLine(uri);
    }
}
```

Is it the intend behavior to wipe /BasePath out from uri and the final result be `http://localhost:7777/controller`?

Comment: Because the `/` in `/controller` indicates "from root" where root is `http://localhost:7777`.

Comment: You need to do `new Uri(baseUri, "./controller")` to state that your path is relative from the current path (denoted by the dot). This will return `http://localhost:7777/BasePath/controller`.

Comment: Or keep your `baseUri` and your `relativeUri` separate. `Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:7777"); Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, "/BasePath/controller");` That way there's nothing to accidentally overwrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to dig into the [documentation for the constructor you're calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_).

`public Uri (Uri baseUri, string relativeUri);`

> Additionally, if the `relativeUri` begins with a slash, then it will replace any relative part of the `baseUri`.

It's the intended behavior. If you specify a relative path that begins with a slash, it assumes that the relative path is the *entire* relative path, so it discards any relative path already included in `baseUri`.

Comment: I do not see that. var myUri = "http://something.com/path1"; var finalUri = new Uri(myUri, "path2"); and finalUri.AbsoluteUri will be "http://something.com/path2".

Comment: In the documentation, it says that the baseUri must end with a trailing slash if you want the path retained.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @SENya You could add another or edit this answer to provide more info. In the OP the base URI already ends with a trailing slash, so adding one can't answer the question. The question was why part of the base uri path gets removed when it's combined with a relative URI. In the OP the relative uri begins with a slash.